# npm install hangs on idealTree step

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install npm, but it consistently hangs on the idealTree step. Here's the trace from -verbose :

```
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', '-verbose' ]
npm info using npm@8.1.2
npm info using node@v17.1.0
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 4ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:/home/sacha/myPhoneBook/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:/home/sacha/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/usr/etc/npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 11ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 11ms
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
npm timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 1ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 28ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 59ms
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 0ms
⸨⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⸩ ⠸ idealTree:myPhoneBook: sill idealTree buildDeps
```

I've seen a few solutions proposed to this online, including setting the registry and removing package-lock.json, but none seemed to work. Could someone suggest another fix ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: This might be a network problem. If you have VPN connection, try disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Had similiar problems with nodejs with running it on windows 11. I have upgraded and downgraded, cleared cache, etc nothing worked.
Installing it on windows10 worked fine though. What OS are u running it on>?

Comment: Hello, I think this should be a comment to the question instead of an answer.

Comment: Hello, I think this should be a comment to the question instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and it might because of bad internet connection. anyway you can use **yarn** instead and if you have problem with that too try to change the registry with `yarn config set registry https://registry.yarnpkg.com`.